# Format Validation Summary

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, validation

All I want to do is an Image to the validation summary and format the hearder text in the validation summary. This is for IE.

```
    .validationSummary{border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:7px;}
    .validationSummary ul{ color:black; list-style-type: square;}


<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" DisplayMode="BulletList" CssClass="validationSummary" EnableClientScript="true" meta:resourcekey="ValidationSummaryResource"/>
```

So basically all I need is a way to add an icon to the validation summary and access the hearder css porperties.

Can I access the header like this: .validationSummary.HeaderText{color:Black;} IT does not seem to be working.

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?

Comment: See edit for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Header like this:

```
 <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" HeaderText ="<span>the following fields require your attention</span>"/>
```

css:

```
.validation_summary{
    background: url(/image.png) no-repeat left;
}
```

Comment: I need the header to be used in a resource file so that it can switch between english and french

Comment: This worked jsut fine because I can set the span tag inside the resource file and still access it through css. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give the UL some padding, a background image and set the background image to display top left.

something like

```
.validationSummary ul{
     padding-left: 50px;
     background: url(your image) no-repeat fixed left top;
}
```

This should match your design with enough tweeking.

Comment: thsi does not show up at all when I try it. i can only get background:url('caution_50.png') to work and show a bunch of repeated images. Also how do access the header properties?